# Right way of using while empty variable

Tags: php, while-loop

I have to find some value in database. But I know that it will appear there between some time period. So I decided to create a function and call this function while this value will not appear. Also I have check if this value will not appear during 10 seconds then break the loop:

```
function get_response($task_id) {    
    $query = "select * from table where task_id = '$task_id'";
    $db->query($query); 
    $result = $db->getResult();
    if (count($result) > 0)
       $response = $result;
    else $response = false;    
    return $response;
}

$start = microtime(true);
while (($res = get_response($task_id)) == false && (microtime(true) - $start) < 10) {
        if ($res != false) {
            print_r($res);
            break;
        }
        if((microtime(true) - $start) >= 10) {
            $response = 'timeout';
            break;
        }
        usleep(100000);
    }
```

But `$res` never returns what I need (always `false`. values exist in database and the problem is causing in while loop). Correct me please in right way.

Comment: maybe $res = get_response($task_id)) != false in the condition?

Comment: Polling the db like this is a real bad idea

Comment: Is that your actual code? I am asking, because there is an error in your SQL-Statement: `tablewhere` (missing space)

Comment: @OcasoProtal No, I just made a mistake replacing table name

Comment: @Masiorama So my code looks fine?

Comment: Actually I wrote down an edit, that noted also another user in his answer...

Answer (score 2):

```
($res = get_response($task_id)) == false
```

you are just going into the while-loop when $res == false, so in the loop it will always be false. Try:

```
($res = get_response($task_id)) != false
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code does not contain any refresh code for page.

Try to use refresh code for the page for every 10 seconds... you can jquery or java-script or Ajax refresh..

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your exact front end scenario, like when you are expecting the results based on what action.

But If you want to keep getting the updated from server, you can definitely try out `HTML5 Server-Sent Events`

All you have to do is create an `EventSource` Object

```
var source = new EventSource("your_php_file.php");
// your_php_file is what will fetch results from database.
```

Then youn can listen to events

```
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log(e.data); //get the data
}, false);
```

There is a nice explanation on [html5rocks wesite-eventsource](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are more things wrong.

In your `get_response` function you don't query your query you only assign it to a variable you don't use.

And I also don't see you changing the `$task_id` anywhere. Is this all the code? Because otherwise you're always trying to query the same task_id. You need to alter it inside your while loop.

And as already mentioned the `$res` will stay `false` inside the while loop. Which should not be a problem if you just print your `$res` after the while loop and don't use it inside your loop, where you don't need it.

Comment: I was inattentive building my question. Sure I execute query and I assign some value to `$task_id`. Now it looks solved